# How to fix Bootstrap 4 content responsiveness in columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a responsive profile page using Bootstrap 4. The point is that on smaller a screen the content floats left while center and right parts are empty. I am talking about the columns of username, country, city, gender, profession, job title. The same issue applies to the Follow and message buttons. They do not look the way they should be on mobile (in the same line)

**I've added a link of code in the comment.**

That issue is happening only on mobile devices. How can I show 2 columns in each row on mobile? Also, fix buttons positions and show them in the same line?

Comment: Here is the link:
https://codepen.io/artyombaykov/pen/JmxGQY

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Then when you need to show us screen width behavior, I'd suggest using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), which allows width resizing. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/unyct4v7/) is a little example of the use of `col-[xs|sm|md|lg|xl]-*`. And why didn't you put your link **directly in your question** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below structure. Also there is no such class as `col-xs-*` in bootstrap 4. You have to use `col-*` class instead for styles that you want to get applied in mobile view.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NErWXE?editors=1100)

```
  <section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="profile-img">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 main-col col-sm-12  col-12 d-flex d-sm-block flex-column align-items-center">
                  <h5>
                    Kshiti Ghelani
                  </h5>
                  <h6>
                    24 Years Old
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-match float-right">Follow</a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message">Message</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Kshiti123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Profession</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Designer</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Gender</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Female</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Job Title</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">UI Designer</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">UK</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>City</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Oxford</p>
                </div>
              </div>



            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tollit munere quo ne, timeam saperet ea mel. Ad vide essent dolores usu, ponderum salutatus ea duo, est alii commune ea. Pro euismod legimus detracto ad. Ei eius expetenda assueverit vis, cu duo sapientem temporibus,
              quo minim nostro ut.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In this example right parts are still empty on mobile. How can all the content be floated to the center, the (name, and age as well under the image)

Comment: Please see updated link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NErWXE?editors=1100

Comment: Changed this line <div class="col-md-4 main-col col-sm-12  col-12 d-flex d-sm-block flex-column align-items-center">

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Welcome @Artyom :)